# Setting AudioManager to SILENT_MODE sets it to Do Not Distrub

Tags: android

Why does this code set to `silent` on some devices and to `Do not disturb` on others? Some have removed silent mode since apk 23, but it even doesn't work on devices that still support that. On devices that run on apk lower than 23, it sets them on `silent`.

```
am= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every APIs

> AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT

returns 0 and will set Ringer mode that will be silent and will not vibrate.Even in the do not disturb context, it does the same.